# Python regex cut pattern string

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I have file with information like this:

```
 id                      : 1234567890
 1)client_name           : Abcd
 2)family_name           : Efgh
 5)phon_number           : 9876543210
 6)address               : street number
 data                    : [42|63] [42|62]

 id                      : 14785236984
 1)client_name           : Abcd
 2)family_name           : Efgh
 5)phon_number           : 987555555555
 6)address               : street number
 data                    : [44|67] [21|1024]          
 id                      : 987456321
 1)client_name           : Abcd
 2)family_name           : Efgh
 5)phon_number           : 98744444444
 6)address               : street number
 data                    : [26|1089] [21|1524]
```

i want to divide this information by regex, because not all the blocks are separate
with new line('\n') so it will be hard for me to do so with split I tried to do with regular expression:

```
^[\s]id[\w\W\s\S\t]+(\[\d{1,}\|\d{1,}\]{,2})$
```

but it take all of the blocks i want the result should be:

1. group one

   ```
    id                      : 1234567890
    1)client_name           : Abcd
    2)family_name           : Efgh
    5)phon_number           : 9876543210
    6)address               : street number
    data                    : [42|63] [42|62]
   ```
2. group two

   ```
    id                      : 14785236984
    1)client_name           : Abcd
    2)family_name           : Efgh
    5)phon_number           : 987555555555
    6)address               : street number
    data                    : [44|67] [21|1024]
   ```
3. group three

   ```
   id                      : 987456321
   1)client_name           : Abcd
   2)family_name           : Efgh
   5)phon_number           : 98744444444
   6)address               : street number
   data                    : [26|1089] [21|1524]
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way seems to be quite simple and easy to read:

```
l = re.split(r'\n+(?=\s*id\b)', s.strip(), flags=re.M)
print l
```

Split by newline/s preceeded by id. Also you take the original string and strip it.

Demo: https://ideone.com/No5vva

Answer (score 1):

This regex will split the input text to groups starting with `id` (you can omit the `.strip()` if you want to keep the whitespaces around). [Explanation of this regexp here](https://regex101.com/r/3dNBML/3).

```
data="""
 id                      : 1234567890
 1)client_name           : Abcd
 2)family_name           : Efgh
 5)phon_number           : 9876543210
 6)address               : street number
 data                    : [42|63] [42|62]

 id                      : 14785236984
 1)client_name           : Abcd
 2)family_name           : Efgh
 5)phon_number           : 987555555555
 6)address               : street number
 data                    : [44|67] [21|1024]
 id                      : 987456321
 1)client_name           : Abcd
 2)family_name           : Efgh
 5)phon_number           : 98744444444
 6)address               : street number
 data                    : [26|1089] [21|1524]
"""

import re
from pprint import pprint

pprint([i.strip() for i in re.findall(r'id\s*:.*?(?=id|\Z)', data, flags=re.DOTALL)], width=120)
```

Output will be list of 3 strings (I put newline between them to see it clearly):

```
['id                      : 1234567890\n'
 ' 1)client_name           : Abcd\n'
 ' 2)family_name           : Efgh\n'
 ' 5)phon_number           : 9876543210\n'
 ' 6)address               : street number\n'
 ' data                    : [42|63] [42|62]',

 'id                      : 14785236984\n'
 ' 1)client_name           : Abcd\n'
 ' 2)family_name           : Efgh\n'
 ' 5)phon_number           : 987555555555\n'
 ' 6)address               : street number\n'
 ' data                    : [44|67] [21|1024]',

 'id                      : 987456321\n'
 ' 1)client_name           : Abcd\n'
 ' 2)family_name           : Efgh\n'
 ' 5)phon_number           : 98744444444\n'
 ' 6)address               : street number\n'
 ' data                    : [26|1089] [21|1524]']
```

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be easier to `split` by whitespace, with lookahead for `id` followed by space:

```
re.compile("\s+(?=id\s{22}:)").split(s)
```

https://ideone.com/FSgVrN

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.split(r'\s(?=id)', s)` to split the whole string into sections, then split each line in the sections, and then split each line based on `:` to convert into a `dict`

```
>>> s="""id                      : 1234567890
...  1)client_name           : Abcd
...  2)family_name           : Efgh
...  5)phon_number           : 9876543210
...  6)address               : street number
...  data                    : [42|63] [42|62]
... 
...  id                      : 14785236984
...  1)client_name           : Abcd
...  2)family_name           : Efgh
...  5)phon_number           : 987555555555
...  6)address               : street number
...  data                    : [44|67] [21|1024]          
...  id                      : 987456321
...  1)client_name           : Abcd
...  2)family_name           : Efgh
...  5)phon_number           : 98744444444
...  6)address               : street number
...  data                    : [26|1089] [21|1524]"""
>>> 
>>> import re
>>> sections = re.split(r'\s(?=id)', s)
>>> ld = [dict(map(str.strip, line.split(':')) for line in section.splitlines() if line) for section in sections]
>>> 
>>> pprint (sections)
['id                      : 1234567890\n'
 ' 1)client_name           : Abcd\n'
 ' 2)family_name           : Efgh\n'
 ' 5)phon_number           : 9876543210\n'
 ' 6)address               : street number\n'
 ' data                    : [42|63] [42|62]\n'
 '\n',
 'id                      : 14785236984\n'
 ' 1)client_name           : Abcd\n'
 ' 2)family_name           : Efgh\n'
 ' 5)phon_number           : 987555555555\n'
 ' 6)address               : street number\n'
 ' data                    : [44|67] [21|1024]          \n',
 'id                      : 987456321\n'
 ' 1)client_name           : Abcd\n'
 ' 2)family_name           : Efgh\n'
 ' 5)phon_number           : 98744444444\n'
 ' 6)address               : street number\n'
 ' data                    : [26|1089] [21|1524]']
>>> 
>>> pprint (ld)
[{'1)client_name': 'Abcd',
  '2)family_name': 'Efgh',
  '5)phon_number': '9876543210',
  '6)address': 'street number',
  'data': '[42|63] [42|62]',
  'id': '1234567890'},
 {'1)client_name': 'Abcd',
  '2)family_name': 'Efgh',
  '5)phon_number': '987555555555',
  '6)address': 'street number',
  'data': '[44|67] [21|1024]',
  'id': '14785236984'},
 {'1)client_name': 'Abcd',
  '2)family_name': 'Efgh',
  '5)phon_number': '98744444444',
  '6)address': 'street number',
  'data': '[26|1089] [21|1524]',
  'id': '987456321'}]
>>>
```